# <badref> when using CallInst::CreateMalloc for a struct type

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to generate LLVM IR for code (in a toy language) similar to the following C++ code:

```
struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
int main() {
  tempVar *a;
  a = new test();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run `verifyModule`, I receive the following error messages:

```
Instruction referencing instruction not embedded in a basic block!
  %malloccall = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 mul nuw (i64 ptrtoint (i32* getelementptr (i32, i32* null, i32 1) to i64), i64 3))
  <badref> = bitcast i8* %malloccall to %test*
```

The following MWE reproduces the issue:

```
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace llvm;

std::map<std::string, StructType *> allocatedClasses;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Type *>> classSizes;

static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);
static std::map<std::string, AllocaInst *> NamedValues;

int main() {
  static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;

  TheModule = std::make_unique<Module>("inputFile", TheContext);

  allocatedClasses["test"] = StructType::create(TheContext, "test");
  classSizes["test"] = std::vector<Type *>(3, Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));
  allocatedClasses["test"]->setBody(classSizes["test"]);

  FunctionType *mainType = FunctionType::get(Builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
  Function *main = Function::Create(mainType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main",
                                    TheModule.get());
  BasicBlock *entry = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", main);
  Builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);

  std::string tV = "tempVar";
  NamedValues[tV] = Builder.CreateAlloca(
      PointerType::get(allocatedClasses["test"], 0), nullptr, tV);
  auto typeSize = ConstantExpr::getSizeOf(allocatedClasses["test"]);
  typeSize =
      ConstantExpr::getTruncOrBitCast(typeSize, Type::getInt64Ty(TheContext));

  CallInst::CreateMalloc(Builder.GetInsertBlock(), Type::getInt64Ty(TheContext),
                         allocatedClasses["test"], typeSize, nullptr, nullptr,
                         "");
  Builder.CreateRet(ConstantInt::get(TheContext, APInt(32, 0)));

  TheModule->print(outs(), nullptr);
  Module *test = TheModule.get();
  verifyModule(*test, &errs());
}
```

I compile this with
`` clang++ `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all` -g ex.cpp ``, using clang version `10.0.0-4ubuntu1`, on x86. When executed, the program outputs:

```
; ModuleID = 'inputFile'
source_filename = "inputFile"

%test = type { i32, i32, i32 }

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %tempVar = alloca %test*
  %malloccall = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 mul nuw (i64 ptrtoint (i32* getelementptr (i32, i32* null, i32 1) to i64), i64 3))
  ret i32 0
}

declare noalias i8* @malloc(i64)
```

and the error message from above.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the function you call](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#ab16e984b0e40d0ca395b70075b8ca251) says "Note: This function does not add the bitcast to the basic block, that is the responsibility of the caller."

I have no idea why not, but the caller is you.

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution was to store the result of `CallInst::CreateMalloc` to a variable, and then call `Builder.Insert()` with that variable as its only argument.